# Completely elastic and inelastic colission

Tags: reference-frames, inertial-frames, collision, elasticity

I know what is preserved in completely inelastic collision: $m_1v_1+m_2v_2=(m_1+m_2)v$.

Now I would like to know what **is preserved** in completely elastic one.

Comment: What is preserved is the momentum, not that equation you wrote there. The equation is just how this conservation may be expressed mathematically in a very special case and for some arbitrarily chosen notations.

Answer (score 1):

In an inelastic collision, total energy is conserved but not *total kinetic energy* (some of the kinetic energy of the system is 'lost' to heat, sound, plastic deformation etc)

In an elastic collision total kinetic energy is fully conserved.

Note also that momentum is always conserved, but on condition no external forces act on the system.

Comment: **So**, my eqation $m_1v_1+m_2v_2=(m_1+m_2)v$ is not correct for inelastic collision ??

Comment: It depends a little but strictly it should be: $m_1v_1+m_2v_2=m_1v_3+m_2v_4$ Sometimes $v_3=v_4$.

Comment: Right, this yours equation gives also solution for completely elastic collision, right ? What do I take for $v_3$ and $v_4$ for completely elastic collision now ?

Comment: What is **external force** here in your answer ?

Comment: For an elastic collision, $v_3$ and $v_4$ determination needs an additional constraint, like conservation of KE. That gives you two equations and two variables.

Comment: An external force... well, is an external force! It is what it means.

Comment: I'm new to physics, sorry! What if we have 2 plastic balls and a glue which joins them. Is this an example of external force this glue ?

Comment: No, the glue is part of the system - no external force there.

Comment: Note that my first equation should really read: $m_1\vec{v_1}+m_2\vec{v_2}=m_1\vec{v_3}+m_2\vec{v_4}$, because the velocities are vectors.

Comment: Right. Could you give me the **two** equations in the 5th comment which I could then try to solve ? Just write them down for me.

Comment: It's not that simple. Rarely can a problem in physics be solved by the *blind* application of a set of formulas, so it would be irresponsible of me to teach you that. You need to study **Conservation of Energy**. Wiki's entry should be very good on that.

Comment: And yet, where it **disappears** the kinetic energy **in words** in the collision of 2 **modelling clay** balls  of the same weight moving in the opposite directions?

Comment: Assuming the joined balls (post-collision) aren't moving then the total KE of the system has been spent on: 1. permanent deformation of the balls, which costs work, 2. noise generated by collision, 3. heat generated, 4. sound generated during collision.

Comment: Right, and usually where is spent **most of KE** ? Thank you for your patience with me. I would bet on 1.

Comment: It's impossible to say but 1. will be a big contributor. But if the balls are very soft the work needed to deform them would be quite small.